# Accessing numpy array element directly using Python for .NET from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, numpy, python.net

I'm making good progress in converting an existing Python script across to VB.NET (please don't ask why), but have run into an issue accessing a numpy array using the row / column index. I feel pretty stupid not being able to sort this, having converted the bulk of the code successfully, so would appreciate any direction. Code snippet:

```
Dim nparray_A = np.random.rand(7, 5)
Console.WriteLine(nparray_A(3)) ' outputs the 4th row from the array
Console.WriteLine(nparray_A(3,3)) ' fails
```

Tried passing in a tuple of (3,3), but same issue.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: If it is a 4x4 array then `nparray_A(3, 3)` would be correct, but perhaps it is an array of arrays and needs `nparray_A(3)(3)`.

Comment: Of course! That did the trick. Many thanks for the advice.